# How do I use kotlin loop to avoid ANR in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using kotlin in my android app. I wrote following function for decoding coordinates :

```
    private fun decodeCoordinates(address: String) {
    var lat: String = ""
    var lng: String = ""
    var flag = true
    var count = 0
    while (count < address.length) {
        if (address[count].equals(',')) {
            flag = false;
            continue
        }
        if (flag) {
            lat += address[count]
        } else {
            lng += address[count]
        }
        count++;
    }
    Log.i("dxdiag", "Lat: $lat")
    Log.i("dxdiag", "Lng: $lng")
}
```

but app hangs, if I remove `continue` , app does not hang

Comment: Just put count++ before continue. If not you are in a infinite loop because count never increases.

Comment: Thanks, worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that you are changing the length of list inside the loop which leads to ANR. Use follinwg loop code:

```
 var length = address.legth
 while (count < length) {
    if (address[count].equals(',')) {
        flag = false;
        continue
    }
    if (flag) {
        lat += address[count]
    } else {
        lng += address[count]
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: It will still do infinite loop once it encounter `','`. You need to increase the count before calling `continue`